# Set index in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, this

I'm working with arrays in jQuery, and I have all the items from an array called `images` displayed on a webpage. When one of the items is clicked (I am using `.click()` for this), I need to find the index of that item in the array, and make `index =` that value. How would this be done? Thanks.

Comment: you want to get which image is clicked?

Comment: @Joie  your question is a bit confusing...perhaps because it is incomplete?

Comment: What is a _jQuery array_? Do you mean a jQuery collection of DOM elements? You can't click on an array, you can only click on a single element. Can you show us what's in `images`?

Comment: Please don't put "(unsolved)" in your title.  Whether the question is solved or not would clearly be indicated by any "accepted" answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> What code will do this?

I'm still trying to figure out what's your actual question, but assuming that you're asking what is `this` in the line of code you posted....

```
$('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'this'" width="450px"/>');
```

basically, `this` is the `window` object in the current context. However, if the line of code above is inside a callback such as a `click` callback...

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var context = this;
});
```

in this case `this` will be the `.next` element that triggered the `click` event. So, basically the line  of code below...

```
$('.large_view').prepend('<img src="'this'" width="450px"/>');
```

will fail because `this` can't be converted to a valid url and because there's a syntax error anyway

Now, I'm still puzzled as to why you claim the code you provided "doesn't work"...maybe because your html and css are wrong...I don't know, you haven't provided them. Here's an example I put together recreating your scenario....

```js
var imagesHtml = '';
var index = 0;
var images = 
    ["http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/jquery_logo.png"
              , "http://ricardofeliciano.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/drupal-and-jquery-logos.png"
              , "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-RTR5yn-b2C8/UaID0dWx-XI/AAAAAAAAGTc/487tXntHlJM/s1600/jQuery+And+Ajax.png"
              , "http://jenniferperrin.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/jquery-logo.png"];



$(function(){
    $.each(images, function(index,value){
       imagesHtml += '<label class="align"><img class="thumbnail" src="'+value+'" /></label>';
    });
    

    $('.gallery').append(imagesHtml);
    $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
    
    $('.next').click(function(){
        index = (index==images.length-1)?0:(index+1);
        $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
    });
    
    $('.previous').click(function(){
        index = (index===0)?(images.length-1):(index-1);
        $('.large_view img').attr('src',images[index]);
    });
});
```

```css
.large_view{
display:inline-block;
    width:90%;
}
.large_view img{
    width:99%;
}
.gallery{
 max-width:600px;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.thumbs{
    
text-align:center;
}
.thumbnail{
width:24%;
}
.next,.previous{
font-weight:bold;
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
    <a class="previous"><<</a>
    <div class="large_view">
        <img/>
    </div>
    <a class="next">>></a>
    <div class="thumbs">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you array is `images` you can use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var images = ["http://i.imgur.com/iekpSfC.gif","http://i.imgur.com/a01mhfU.gif","http://i.imgur.com/WLIq7iK.gif","http://i.imgur.com/YbJIX8K.gif","http://i.imgur.com/Ctn6hrr.gif"],
    figure = document.querySelector("figure");

images.forEach( function (element) {
    var image = new Image(150,80);
        image.src = element;
        figure.appendChild(image)
});

//getting the image index

$("figure img").click( function () {
     var imageIndex = $(this).attr("src");
     alert(images.indexOf(imageIndex));// indexOf will return the index in the array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure></figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this will work:

```
var num = $(this).attr('src');
index = images.indexOf(num);
```

Note: If the code is used, `images` should be changed to the name of the array you are using.

Comment: It is not very nice to copy my answer and just post it like that @Joie anyway good luck!